# _src_module__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__ is not a function

Tags: javascript, webpack

Экспортирую функцию из файла module.js.
При обычном импорте появляется ошибка, что доступен только default export.
При импорте через default, возникает ошибка, что импортированная функция не является функцией.

Использую webpack5

[image: Ошибка при импорте через default]

[image: Как указан импорт]

[image: Как указан экспорт]

[image: Настройки WebPack]

С чем может быть связана такая ошибка?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Пожалуйста, приводите исходный код в виде текста.